# ISupportIncrementalLoading loads more items than required

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP I have a `ListView` that is populated incrementally using the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` Interface for infinite scrolling.

This list is on a page `PageX` and as soon as I navigate to this page, the `ListView` gets populated.

This somethimes works and sometimes  doesn't. problem is caused when I navigate to `PageX`, the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` is called more than once ( for the first time only, for further scrolling it works fine ).

Here's my code:

```
    public class ItemsToShow : ObservableCollection<SearchResultViewModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private SearchResponse ResponseObject { get; set; } = new SearchResponse();
    private MetadataReply Metadata { get; set; } = new MetadataReply();
    SearchResultViewModel viewModel = null;


    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get
        {
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeStaticClass.NextPageToken) && !SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest) || SomeStaticClass.StopIncrementalLoading)
                return false;

            if(SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest)
            {
                using (var db = new DbContext())
                {
                    var json = db.UpdateResponse.First(r => r.LanguageId == DataStore.Language).JsonResponse;
                    Metadata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateApiResponse>(json).response.metadata.reply;
                }

                var returnObject = SomeStaticClass.SearchResponse;
                ResponseObject = returnObject.response;               
            }
            else
            {
                var returnObject = new SearchApiCall().CallSearchApiAsync(
                            SomeStaticClass.QueryString,
                            SomeStaticClass.NextPageToken,
                            SomeStaticClass.Filters).Result;
                ResponseObject = returnObject.response;
            }

           return ResponseObject.documents.Count > 0;     
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
        if (SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest) SomeStaticClass.Facet = ResponseObject.facets;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
        {

            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                foreach (var item in ResponseObject.documents)
                {
                    this.Add(new SearchResultViewModel { .... });
                }
            });

            SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest = false;
            SomeStaticClass.NextPageToken = ResponseObject.pageToken;

            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                SearchResultPage.searchResultPage.FilterButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            });

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };

        }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

My `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="SearchResultListView"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="SearchResultListView_ItemClick">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>               
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:SomeViewModel">

            <Grid Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind qqq}/>                

                <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind xxx}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind yyy}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">                               
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind aaa}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind bbb}"  />
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EducationalLevel}"/

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="4">                        
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Language}"/>                        
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ccc}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind of the page that has this `ListView`:

```
    public sealed partial class SearchResultPage
    {   
        public static SearchResultPage searchResultPage { get; private set; }
        private SearchResultParameterWrapper ReceivedParameter { get; set; } = new SearchResultParameterWrapper();        

        public SearchResultPage()
        {        
            InitializeComponent();          
            NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
            searchResultPage = this;
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {                       
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back) FilterButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest = true;
            SomeStaticClass.Filters = new FilterParametersWrapper();           


            ReceivedParameter = (SearchResultParameterWrapper)e.Parameter;
            if (ReceivedParameter != null)
            {
                SomeStaticClass.QueryString = ReceivedParameter.QueryString;
                SomeStaticClass.Filters = ReceivedParameter.Filters;
                SomeStaticClass.RestoreOldFilters = ReceivedParameter.RestoreOldFilters;

                if(SomeStaticClass.IsFirstRequest)
                    await HandleNoResult(ReceivedParameter);
            }


        }

        private async Task HandleNoResult(SearchResultParameterWrapper parameter)
        {
            if (!ApiStore.IsConnected())
            {
                Toast.ShowToast(MainPage.mainPage.ViewModel._APP_check_network, ToastRow);
                return;
            }

            MyProgressRing.IsActive = true;

            SearchResultListView.ItemsSource = null;
            SearchResultListView.Items.ToList().Clear();
            SearchResponse responseObject = null;
            SearchApiResponse apiResponse = null;
            try
            {               
                SomeStaticClass.StopIncrementalLoading = true;

                SomeStaticClass.SearchResponse = await new SearchApiCall().CallSearchApiAsync(parameter.QueryString, null, parameter.Filters);
                apiResponse = SomeStaticClass.SearchResponse;
                responseObject = apiResponse.response;

                if (responseObject.documents.Count <= 0)
                {                  
                    NoResultsTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    FilterButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    return;
                }
                else
                { 
                    SearchResultListView.ItemsSource = new ItemsToShow();
                    SomeStaticClass.StopIncrementalLoading = false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                MyProgressRing.IsActive = false;
            }
        }        


        public bool Reload() { return Reload(null); }
        private bool Reload(object param)
        {
            System.Type type = Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;
            if (Frame.BackStack.Any())
            {                
                param = ReceivedParameter;
            }
            try { return Frame.Navigate(type, param); }
            finally { Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.Last()); }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:

I've update my code. Same problem remains and another problem arises ie, The page sometimes goes blank ( after showing items for one or two seconds):

```
public class ItemsToShow : ObservableCollection<SearchResultViewModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private SearchResponse ResponseObject { get; set; } = new SearchResponse();       
    private bool hasMoreItems { get; set; } = true;

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        set
        {
            hasMoreItems = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (SomeCondition) return false;
            return hasMoreItems;               
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        Task.Delay(10);
        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
        {
            if (IsFirstRequest)
            {
                HasMoreItems = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResponseObject.someProperty) ? false : true;
                IsFirstRequest = false;
            }
            else
            {   
                ResponseObject = await new SomeClass().SomeMethod();                 
                HasMoreItems = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResponseObject.someProperty) ? false : true;
            }

            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                foreach (var item in ResponseObject.documents)
                {             
                    this.Add(PrepareViewModel(item));
                }
            });

            await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                SearchResultPage.searchResultPage.FilterButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            });                            
            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = count };               
        }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

Comment: From your segment code I could not reproduce your issue. Could you share a simple project?

Comment: I suspect that the issue might be in the page which uses your `SearchResultListView`. Can you add that code?

Comment: @Necoras Updated my question with the code behind

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: @ravikumar I experienced this issue many months before. In that, I called the function(to load items) one time manually when the app launches but we don't want to do it. So make sure that you didn't call the function manually.

Comment: I am sure I am not calling the function manually anywhere. I am only returning true or false from the getter manually if it is the first time. I don't this that should break things.

Comment: You have implemented incremental loading in the wrong way. Async call should be done in `LoadMoreItemsAsync` where you also set `HasMoreItems`. Task.Result is bad, it will block the UI and cause deadlocks. Why not try [IncrementalLoadingCollection](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/dev/helpers/IncrementalLoadingCollection/) from uwp community toolkit?

Comment: @Jessica I've updated my question with your suggestions. I hope this is the correct way. But the problem remains.

Comment: I also tried CommunityToolkit. It **always** makes one extra call.

Comment: I am not sure. What's your issue here? What happens if it's called twice?

Comment: To load items, I make an API call. So in my case two API calls are made. This is not acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't try to load the same items twice, I don't really see much issue with it. It's like having two sets of data on load, and then loading one set on scroll.

But you probably would wonder why it's doing this, and here is how I understand it.

During the initial load, `ISupportIncrementalLoading.LoadMoreItemsAsync` will **always be called more than once** unless there's no data to populate. This behavior is most likely caused by the design of `ListView` virtualization.

My guess is that before the `ListView` decides how many items to load initially, it needs to know the item height in order to calculate the number of items to virtualize. Therefore, it first loads one item to get the height, do the calculations and call `LoadMoreItemsAsync` again. This is why if you put a *breakpoint* inside `LoadMoreItemsAsync`, you will see the `count` value always gives you `1` the first time the method is called.

To avoid this behavior, you cannot simply ignore the first call 'cause incremental loading won't be triggered when there's no items in view. So you can hack around to ignore not the first but second call.

Take the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/8c61e7ddca8df69f39adf61032c449146b06b9bb/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/IncrementalLoadingCollection/IncrementalLoadingCollection.cs#L232) from *UWP Community Toolkit* for example, you can do something like this -

```
private bool? _firstLoadJustPassed;
private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_firstLoadJustPassed == true)
    {
        _firstLoadJustPassed = false;
        return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = 0 };
    }

    uint resultCount = 0;
    _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;

    try
    {
        if (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            IEnumerable<IType> data = null;
            try
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                data = await LoadDataAsync(_cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // The operation has been canceled using the Cancellation Token.
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (OnError != null)
            {
                OnError.Invoke(ex);
            }

            if (data != null && data.Any() && !_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                resultCount = (uint)data.Count();

                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    Add(item);
                }

                if (!_firstLoadJustPassed.HasValue)
                {
                    _firstLoadJustPassed = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HasMoreItems = false;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        IsLoading = false;

        if (_refreshOnLoad)
        {
            _refreshOnLoad = false;
            await RefreshAsync();
        }
    }

    return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = resultCount };
}
```

There might be more elegant solutions than this but again like I said, I personally don't see such a big issue with this behavior and I would use [`IncrementalLoadingCollection`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/IncrementalLoadingCollection/) from the toolkit than writing my own implementation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more as to how do I make use of this. And I don't understand the use of cancellation token ( also as I am implementing the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface, how can I have `LoadMoreItemsAsync` that also takes a cancellationtoken. And on a different note, if the height of `ListView` is required, why doesn't giving it a `MinHeight` work ?

Comment: You can have a look at how `IncrementalLoadingCollection` is used in the toolkit GitHub page. But really if you don't want to use it you just need to take the `_firstLoadJustPassed` bit(two `if` statements) and put it into your own `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method. Note the height is the item height, not the ListView's height. Item height is calculated during runtime, you cannot set it. Even if you could, you wouldn't be able to pass it to the internal incremental loading implementation.

Comment: How did you go?

Comment: I went a completely different way. I, kept i timestamp of when the items are loaded last time and on every call to loadasyc I checked if the last call was made and returned immediately if it was made les than a second ago, otherwise I allowed the rest of the function to execute. This worked for me.

Comment: I think solutions can vary but it's important to understand why it's doing this. So hope my answer has helped in that way. :)

Comment: Your answer definitely helped me understand